# Где в Android Studio находится файл R.java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, r.java-file

Где в Android Studio находится файл R.java?
Пробовал искать по этому скриншоту, но в новой версии Android Studio по этому пути файла R.java нет

[image]

Comment: а для чего, если не секрет?) модифицировать его все равно нельзя

Comment: И какой именно `R` вам нужен? - он есть в каждой библиотеке, собранной для Андроида, в самом фреймворке и в каждом **вашем** модуле. Если ваш, то внизу скриншота папка `source` - в ней поищите. Или жмите `F4` либо `ctrl+B` на любом упоминании этого класса в коде.

Comment: так же это автогенерируемый класс, он появляется только после компиляции/сборки проекта и будет пересоздан при следующих компиляциях, при этом, если добавятся ресурсы, то изменятся ID ранее созданных, поэтому его нельзя модифицировать и вообще как то использовать в работе приложения

Comment: @iFr0z, мне просто интересно, как оно всё устроено)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С версии студии 3.3.0 такой файл больше не генерируется. https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#behavior-changes

> Faster R class generation for library projects: Previously, the
>   Android Gradle plugin would generate an R.java file for each of your
>   project's dependencies and then compile those R classes alongside your
>   app's other classes. **The plugin now generates a JAR containing your
>   app's compiled R class directly, without first building intermediate
>   R.java classes**. This optimization may significantly improve build
>   performance for projects that include many library subprojects and
>   dependencies, and improve the indexing speed in Android Studio.